# CKEditor 4.5.8, Keystrokeslimit, Undo plugin

Tags: ckeditor, undo, ckeditor4.x

If I change the strokesLimit=25 to 5 in undomanager, to allow people to undo less, do you foresee any other issues for the users?

If no, Why is the strokeslimit so high, google docs and other tools seems to have time based limit or less key strokes? Do CKEditor have time based limits?

Will upgrading CKeditor from 4.5 to recent(5+) will help?

Comment: So what's your problem with 25 ? My guess, if people want to undo less they will use backspace ?

Comment: Thanks, @SAZ for your thoughts. I understand to undo less backspace can be an option.

Comment: SAZ, Users of my app are using google docs a lot and so they expect undo to work in similar fashion. Do we have anything related to time based undo such as events which are done with 10ms gap will be grouped together for undo as in google docs. On the other hand, can you share with me the feature difference between undo in CKeditor 4 and CKeditor 5